# Regex to Parse MySQL Column Type for Floats, Decimals, Doubles

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In MySQL the results of DESCRIBE table_name or SHOW COLUMNS FOR table_name contains a Type field which for floats, decimals and doubles can look like decimal(15,3) or just decimal. The same follows for float and double.

I currently have:

```
'/^float|decimal|double(?:\((\d+),(\d+)\))?$/'
```

How do I need to modify this regular expression so that the (15,3) would be optional?

**Update (2):** 
Even though the (15,3) is optional, I still need to capture the two values if they are there. Adding the ? worked but now it doesn't capture the 15 and 3. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'/^(?:float|decimal|double)(?:\((\d+),(\d+)\))?/'
```

Surround the `\((\d+),(\d+)\)` part with a non-capturing group (`(?:)`) and make it optional (`?`).

By the way: Is the `$` at the end missing intentionally?

Comment: No. I didn't know I needed it.

Comment: I still need to capture the optional part if it exists. How does that change the regex?

Comment: @NoahGoodrich The two numbers are still captured if they exist ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append `?` to the group you want to make optional. It means "at most one". So you would need:

```
'/^(?:float|decimal|double)(\((\d+),(\d+)\))?/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read data from the information_schema.columns table.

For example:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns;
```

DATA_TYPE returns - decimal

COLUMN_TYPE returns - decimal(5,2)

Comment: I can't rely on having access to directly read INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database is always accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "^(((float|decimal|double)(\\([[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+\\))?))$";
```

This will match both of your cases. It expects either float, decimal or double alone **or** decimal(at least one digit **,** at least one digit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this blog can help you!!!

http://qpassablog.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/expresiones-regulares-en-mysql.html

Ok, sorry for the inconvenience. This is the solution:

To check if the field value is a decimal number, you can use the following expresion

REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+.{0,1}[[:digit:]]*$'

Example: select '3.222' REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+.{0,1}[[:digit:]]*$' as prueba;

Answer (score -1):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database is very useful because it breaks up the information. However, it can be incredibly slow to access. On my web host it takes 95 seconds!